# How to fix "Object variable or With block variable not set"

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I'm only getting this error when I try the macro across multiple boxes that do not all have the same selection style to start.

```
Sub Remove_Decimals()
'
' Remove_Decimals Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+V
'
    If Selection.Style = "Percent" Then
    Else:
    Selection.NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.0_);_($* (#,##0.0);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
    Selection.NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0_);_($* (#,##0);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you share a sample screenshot of the data that causes the error?

Comment: yup I just added it to the question. Selecting all those cells before applying the macro gives me an error. (wouldn't let me post the picture as a screenshot not enough reputation points)

Comment: Can't reproduce the error the screenshot and code you provided. Add `Option Explicit` to the top of the module and rerun. Does it flag a possible typo?

Comment: no typos are being flagged. The marco works sometimes but not always and im not sure what exactly the parameters are that cause the error.

Answer (score 1):

Working off `Selection` assumes that there is a selection. If nothing is selected, `Selection` is `Nothing`, and accessing its members throws error 91 like you're getting.

Working off `Selection.Style` requires that the current selection has a `Style` property, but `Selection` can be a `Shape` or a `Chart`, not necessarily a `Range` of cells.

The only way to make sure of that is to validate the data type of the `Selection` - add this guard clause to the beginning of your code, should fix it:

```
If Not TypeOf Selection Is Excel.Range Then Exit Sub
```

Now that we know we're looking at a `Range`, it's safe to cast it to that interface and do away with the late-bound code that's only resolved at run-time (and risk error 438 for any typo... which `Option Explicit` won't be able to pick up):

```
Dim selectedCells As Range
Set selectedCells = Selection
```

Now, I know we usually prefer positive conditionals, but making an empty conditional block with the whole logic in the `Else` part makes no sense. Invert that condition and remove the empty block - and if you're going to write a value only to overwrite it the next statement, skip straight to the second assignment:

```
If selectedCells.Style <> "Percent" Then
    selectedCells.NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0_);_($* (#,##0);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
End If
```

That said, since the macro is named "remove decimals" it might be a good idea to first validate that we're looking at a numeric value - but we can't do this for the `selectedCells` range, we need to validate each individual cell separately (because `selectedCells.Value` is a 2D variant array given any multiple-cells range).

So, recap:

```
Public Sub RemoveDecimals()
    'bail out if no cells are selected:
    If Not TypeOf Selection Is Excel.Range Then Exit Sub 

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In selectedCells
        'ignore non-numeric and percentage cells:
        If IsNumeric(cell.Value) And cell.Style <> "Percent" Then
            cell.NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0_);_($* (#,##0);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (just reusing your code):

```vb
Sub Remove_Decimals()
'
' Remove_Decimals Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+V
'
Dim rngCell As Range
    For Each rngCell In Selection

        If rngCell.Style <> "Percent" Then
            rngCell.NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.0_);_($* (#,##0.0);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
            rngCell.NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0_);_($* (#,##0);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
        End If
    Next rngCell
End Sub
```

Not sure why you are applying the formatting twice though?